# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x-2}=5\left(x-2\right)\sqrt{y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Based on the equation it looks like I need an integrating factor:

$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x-2}=5\left(x-2\right)\sqrt{y}$

**Integrating factor**

$e^{\int\frac{1}{x-2}\;dx}$, which when integrated gives

$\ln\left|x-2\right|$

or

$x-2$

But this is the part where I get very confused with the integrating factor. I believe (though I don't understand why) the left side simplifies to:

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x-2\right)y$

and when writing out the entire equation I get:

$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x-2\right)y = \left(x-2\right)\left(5\left(x-2\right)\sqrt{y}\right)$

Any helps as to where I go from here?  The math after this point doesn't make sense to me, which leads me to believe I made a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Um, the RHS can be simplified:  $$5(x-2)^2\sqrt{y}$$

Comment: @SimpleArt right, my mistake :-)

Comment: the equation is not linear so the integrating factor makes no sense. Try the subsitution $v=\sqrt y$. These types of equations are known as Bernoulli Equations.

Comment: You can't generally use integrating factors when you have a $\sqrt{y}$ as on the RHS of your differential equation.

Comment: @Chilango I'm trying the method for Bernoulli Equations and I get $v=1$, since $v=y^{n-1}=y^{1-1}=1$, so how am I supposed to obtain the derivative of y if I only have constants?

Comment: $n=1/2$ so the substitution is $v=y^{1-\frac{1}{2}}=y^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: @Chilango :facepalm:  thanks, it's been a long day :(

Comment: Sure. I've had my share...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=u+2$; then

$$u \frac{dy}{du} + y = 5 u^2 \sqrt{y}$$

or

$$\frac{d}{du} (u y) = 5 u^{3/2} \sqrt{u y}$$

or

$$\frac{d(u y)}{\sqrt{u y}} = 5 u^{3/2} du \implies 2 \sqrt{u y} = 2 u^{5/2}+ 2 C $$

Finally,

$$y(x) = \frac{\left [(x-2)^{5/2}+C \right ]^2}{x-2} = (x-2)^4+ 2 C (x-2)^{3/2}+\frac{C^2}{x-2}$$